# Save data from WebSocket messages only once per 5 seconds

Tags: reactjs, websocket, lodash

I have a simple React component, where I subscribe to WebSocket message in `useEffect` hook:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    ws.onmessage = (response) => {
      const stream = JSON.parse(response.data)
      updateState([...stream ])
    }

    return () => ws.close()
  }, [])
```

And this is works just fine: I receive data from WebSocket and set it to state. But my problem is I receive really too many messages (more than I actually need), and I want to limit it to one state change per 5 seconds. Does not seem like I can use setTimeout or Lodash debounce/throttle here (or I can't find how). Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can throttle the `onmessage` handle to only allow one update per 5 seconds:

```
useEffect(() => {
  ws.onmessage = _.throttle((response) => {
    const stream = JSON.parse(response.data)
    updateState([...stream])
  }, 5000, { leading: true })

  return () => ws.close()
}, [])
```

**Note**: using throttle is more fitting here. It means that every 5 second, one change would be applied. If you'll use debounce, and the rate of updates would be too fast, no update would be applied until the events would stop for awhile.